# Prove using classical logic that $q \to r, r \to p \vdash_c \neg (\neg p \land q)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Prove using classical logic that $q \to r, r \to p \vdash_c \neg (\neg p \land q)$

Hello, I'm finding hard to prove this...

I've been to use the left implication rule, Modus Tollens, Disjunctive syllogism. But I can not seem to find a way to derivate this...

Can anyone provide help?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: *Hint:* $(q\to p)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot q)\lor p$

Comment: Please, be more precise about the inference rules you are allowed to use.

Comment: Looks like a job for indirect proof.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco sorry for the late reply... I can use the rules mentioned in this site https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/classical-logic

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Assume $(\lnot p \land q)$ and use $(\land \text E)$ to derive $\lnot p$ and $q$.

With $q$ derive $p$, using $(\to \text E)$ twice.

Now use $(\to \text E)$ to derive $\bot$ and conclude with $\lnot (\lnot p \land q)$ using $(\to \text I)$.

*Note*: the names of the rule are those of page 33.

Comment: What do you mean by "Assume $(\neg p \land q)$", sorrry, I think I'm getting confused... Because I have $q \to r, r \to p \vdash_c \neg (\neg p \land q)$. How could I assume $(\neg p \land q)$ ?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I think I just solved.

Comment: @MR_chep - If everything is clear, you can upvote and accept the answer (to keep the website tidy), otherwise you can ask for further explanations.